# Can't find the env passed into execve function

Tags: c, execve

I would like to see if the environment variable I have passed in the **execve()** function has really been passed, so I made this code (Main.c):

```
int main(){

    char PATH[4];
    strcpy(PATH, "bin");
    char * newargv[] = {"./get","", (char*)0};
    char * newenviron[] = {PATH};
    execve("./get", newargv, newenviron);
    perror("execve");
    return 0;
}
```

(get.c):

```
int main()
{
    const char* s = getenv("PATH");
    printf("PATH :%s\n",s);

}
```

But, when I execute the binary issued by Main.c, I get this output:

> PATH :(null)

whereas I want to see

> PATH: bin

Do you have any explanation?

Comment: Well, `PATH` is of size 3 but you copy a string of length 4 into it (remember the NUL terminator `'\0'`)...

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post but resolving the problem of strcpy changed nothing :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your string buffer PATH is not large enough for the string you're trying to put into it.
2. The environment string needs to be `"PATH=bin"`, not just `"bin"`.
3. As the other answer indicates, you need to end your list of environment strings with a null pointer, i.e. `char *newenviron[] = {PATH, 0};`.

You might try examining the environment structure that's passed to your program before modifying it, to see the necessary format.  Here's an example of how to do this: http://nibot-lab.livejournal.com/115837.html

Comment: FWIW, OP fixed #1 in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Environment strings must be in the format of `VARIABLE_NAME=value of the variable`.

Your `PATH` variable (the C variable, not the environment variable) should be a string with the contents `PATH=bin`.

Also, you need to end it with an extra null (along with the null that comes with the last string, of course) to indicate that there are no more strings in the environment.

From the `execve(2)` manpage (emphasis mine):

> The argument envp is also a pointer to a **null-terminated array** of character pointers to **null-terminated strings**.  A pointer to this array is normally stored in the global variable environ. These strings pass information to the new process that is not directly an
>        argument to the command (see environ(7)).

and from the `environ(7)` manpage:

> An array of strings called the environment is made available by execve(2) when a process begins.  By convention these strings have the form ``name=value''.

Comment: The 'two nulls' bit is puzzling.  Each string needs to be terminated by a null byte (one type of null), and the list of pointers to the environment strings needs to be terminated by a null pointer (another type of null).  But that's the only meaning I can think which makes any sense for 'two nulls', and it isn't clear from your answer that you meant that.